# Problem calculating percentage for body width

Tags: css, frontend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem calculating percentage for body width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996736/problem-calculating-percentage-for-body-width)

I do need to build a classic 960px layout and I have to convert that 960px into %.
So, I do use `960px / 16px = 60%`, right?

```
Note: 960px = body width
      16px = font size
```

**Problem.** The `body {width:60%} /*960 / 16px*/` is a lot smaller than body width 960px at same screen dimensions/resolution/width.

Guess, I am doing something wrong.

I know that just resizing it to 74% looks better but then I have to re-calculate all my layout (margins, paddings, widths) to fit that 74%.

I have read a lot fluid/responsive/elastic articles and I can not find out/understand how to proper calculate a proper body size.

> I do realize that I was doing this wrong!

See below. Thanks!